# How to know if its really god?

Tags: gods

Imagine a world has got one god. (This is just for my own Curiosity, not any specific idea intended, and couldn't find better place to ask)

One day he decides to show himself in a form(any) into creature(say human like people)
How can he prove he is really god and not a high-tech (or whatever) creature- alien?

Comment: Replicate something from scripture if the subject of said god have scripture with his deeds.

Comment: Fraud and other thing possible?

Comment: Moses was not the God, and it took him quite a while using some terrible powers to convince Pharaoh of his divine connections.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. See you've chosen an answer--it's considered good etiquette to wait at least 24 hours before choosing an answer to give those folks in other countries and time zones time to answer. Not a requirement and you can do as you please, but choosing an answer 50 minutes in might cause you to miss out on some great answers! (Because others might not bother to answer when they see you've already chosen an answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Clarke's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) states that he cannot.

> Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

No matter what form he manifests in, no matter what miracles he provides, those miracles could be duplicated through sufficiently advanced technology. However, you are maybe setting the bar too high. It is usually enough for almost everyone to believe that he is a god. Big flashy miracles in public places should be enough. Smite a few non-believers with miraculous powers.

Manifest as a burning bush on a morning talk show and have conversation with the host that is not inane and trivial. That would be pretty clearly miraculous because it is so clearly impossible. (sarcasm)

If you are really omnipotent, you can just put the belief in everyone's mind, but from a story perspective, that seems really cheap. This still doesn't prove that he isn't a hyper advanced alien, but what is proof anyway? Everyone believes it.

Comment: Hah, ninja'd, I was just typing up an answer based on the same idea :)

Comment: @AdaliaBooks If you see anything I missed, I would love to hear it.

Comment: No, I think you covered the points I was going to make.

Comment: Loved the sarcasm part lol

Comment: @Nemexia Where is the sarcasm part?

Comment: @ManojKumar (sarcasm)

Answer (score 0):

If he is truly omnipotent, everyone should instantly know he is God the moment he wants them to.

If he is a deity such as a Greek god, all he would need to show is supernatural powers that help(if he destroy things people would think demon rather than god) the people. People who don't believe in magic would be unswayed but eventually if no alternative explanation appears plausible, most people would come to believe it.

Comment: Some sort of mind manipulation of other creatures?

Comment: @Nemexia Maybe!

Answer (score 0):

This will greatly depend on the flavor of god that you're talking about.

In Christianity the emphasis is on faith, not proof, and on the concept of FREE WILL.

A god that simply changes hearts and minds simply at will rather than allowing the choice is definitely not like the god of Christianity.

**But, should a god do that, should a god simply change people's minds, that would not actually be proof. It would be proof that the person has the power to that, but a technology/alien power far beyond our own capabilities could in theory do that.**

It's hard to imagine a world in which a god allows evil but does not allow free will. That's not the world we live in, certainly.

**It doesn't matter how the god tries to prove it--from changing the rules of gravity to the laws of physics, and even, if they created a whole Eden-like planet--it would simply prove that they have powers normally attributed to a god, whatever the source might be.**

**But here's the rub. What's the definition of god?** If someone can do what is normally attributed to god, whatever the source of that power (for all we know, god is just a sufficiently advanced alien creator), if someone can do those things they would be considered god-like UNLESS that power can be stripped from them and used by anyone.

Comment: Very good answer! Thanks. By God i mean the one who created that universe and not essentially our own universe. I was talking general

Comment: @Nemexia If you like it, vote it up!

Comment: Really would like, but idont have enough rep